# Backend for flutter

Tags: database, firebase-realtime-database, flutter, backend

I'm creating an app which will consist multiple login(each login will have some little different functionality) but will be connected to same database to show the same data to each of them, I read somewhere that firebase can't do it, can SQL is capable of doing it? Or which one should I use, any suggestion please

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by firebase can't do it, as I know firebase support multiple types of authentication eg: email/password & phone number & third party auth providers & custom token and so on..., You can even implement all of them in a single app but am not sure why you will need that, Apart from that SQL also doesn't counts on authentication logic you want to implement just its data storage you can implement and combines authentications logics you want in backend still have single DB to store your users authentication credentials it doesn't matter if it's SQL or firebase database or firestore

Comment: I didn't meant about the type of authentication, suppose my app is for a college where student and teachers can log in, and teachers will have more features than student, which means there will a totally different page in the app for teachers and student, where the information will be same for both but the actions will be different, and that I've tried through firebase and even when I try to login as teacher it logs me in as student, and for authentication if I'll use SQL(SQLite/sqflite actually) I'll use Django in combination, I hope you got my point, I'm sorry I didn't expressed it well

Comment: What you want to achieve It likes to implement role-based access control (RBAC)
with firebase checks this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3hj_r_N0qMs